# Where is dos2unix in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-20.04

I want to use `dos2unix` so I installed the `tofrodos` package, but it still says `dos2unix: command not found`.

So I ran:

```
apt-file update; apt-file search dos2unix
```

And it gives zero result.

Where is dos2unix in Ubuntu 20.04? Has it been replaced by an equivalent utility?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the description of the package `tofrodos` in synaptic:

> Tofrodos comprises one program, "fromdos" alias "todos", which converts
>   text files to and from these formats. Use "fromdos" to convert DOS
>   text files to the Unix format, and "todos" to convert Unix text files
>   to the DOS format.

What is wrong with dos2unix and unix2dos is beyond me, and I think it is unbelievable that the package doesn't even make aliases for people who have used linux before and expect dos2unix and unix2dos.

Comment: And another thing... If the idea is that "fromdos" and "todos" are more friendly than "unix2dos" and "dos2unix" why on earth is the package called "tofordos"?

Comment: You can do this if you want to: `username@linuxbox:/usr/bin# sudo ln -s fromdos dos2unix
username@linuxbox:/usr/bin# sudo ln -s todos unix2dos`

Comment: I think the todos/fromdos tools allow for in-place editing of a file, and thus, can be easily included into the "external commands" menu of some GUI-based text editors. With dos2unix a tempfile was needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is dos2unix in Ubuntu 2010.04?

On Ubuntu 20.04+, use the
[Advanced Packaging Tool (APT)](https://superuser.com/tags/apt/info)
to install `dos2unix` :

```
sudo apt install -y dos2unix
```

To find out *where* it's installed, I ran `which dos2unix`, which
yielded `/usr/bin/dos2unix`.